# Mysql 5.5 Stored Procedure performance issue

Tags: mysql, linux

We are using mysql 5.5. The performance of a stored procedure is very slow.

How to improve the stored procedure performance by changing the mysql system properties?

The stored procedure contains joins to various tables (14). The size of DB is 82.5 MB

Currently having the default Mysql system parameters

```
-- 'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '134217728'
-- join_buffer_size 131072
-- 'key_buffer_size', '8388608'
-- 'max_heap_table_size', '16777216'
-- 'read_buffer_size', '131072'
-- 'read_rnd_buffer_size', '262144'
-- 'sort_buffer_size', '2097152'
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is the mysql settings that cause the issue and not the code of the stored procedure itself? How did you identify that these particular settings are the ones that need tweaking?

Comment: The Stored procedure execution is slow , as the data is growing .The CPU utilization in more that 100% will executing the SP.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not an answer to my question! Again, how do you know that the SP performance problems are **NOT** caused by the code of the SP? How did you identify that these particular settings are the ones that need tweaking?